# Do we need to declare data type for a string url in angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I declared a private variable and assigned it to a string. Do I have to declare its data type?

private pageUrl = 'company/'

private pageUrl: string = 'company/'

Which of the above code is correct? If I use the latter code, tslint shows an error.

Comment: Both are technically correct, but the second is redundant as the type is inferred, so you should prefer the first

Comment: @user184994 is correct - the first example you provided is preferred because it makes your code less verbose - See: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferrable-types/

Comment: It's a matter of preference. There are projects where the convention is to explicitly declare types, even when they are inferred, such as your second example. Personally I'd go with the first.

Answer (score 0):

`private pageUrl = 'company/';`

This way you explicit declare the type of pageUrl to string   so the initialized value will be restricted to string, and this consider a good practice.

`private pageUrl = 'company/'`

In this case typescript will not restrict the type of the value that you gone to assign to pageUrl  after you initialize `pageUrl` typescript will do something called **type inference** to determine the type of `pageUrl`.

[Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)